# Unable to Apply 'key' Prop to React Component Within a Mapped Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-slick

[image]I am encountering difficulties applying the key prop to a React component within a mapped array in a Next.js application. The code snippet involves a Slider component and a mapped array of Image components. Despite providing a unique key for each element within the .map() function, the React application does not recognize the key prop, and I'm experiencing unexpected behavior.

```
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import mediaPlaceHolder from "@public/assets/icons/mediaplaceholder.png";

export default function NetworkSlider({ data }) {
  const settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 7,
    slidesToScroll: 7,
    initialSlide: 0,
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {data
          .sort((a, b) => {
            return a.display_priority - b.display_priority;
          })
          .slice(0, 21)
          .map((network) => (
            <div key={network.id} className="flex justify-center">
              <Image
                src={
                  network.logo_path !== null
                    ? `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${network.logo_path}`
                    : mediaPlaceHolder
                }
                width={"300"}
                height={"500"}
                className=" rounded-lg h-auto w-auto"
                alt={`Logo of ${network.provider_name} `}
                priority={true}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
      </Slider>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: Probably it recognized key prop, but some keys are duplicated. Check if you have duplicate id values in your network objects.

Comment: What is unclear about the error? Somewhere in the data you are mapping you've two elements with non-unique id values used as keys. Check your data.

Comment: It it possible that some of your 'network' objects have an 'id' value of undefined? If two or more have undefined ids, that would cause a duplicate key

Answer (score 0):

The common error for this will be that you have a duplicate network `id` in your array and the key for each item from the mapped array needs to be unique.

Let's knock off some possible scenarios.

1. If the `id` is present in the array, then there's another network with an existing `id`
2. The `id` doesn't exist

The easiest solution will be to add an array index to the key prop as so:

```
 {data.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.display_priority - b.display_priority;
          })
          .slice(0, 21)
          .map((network, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="flex justify-center">
              <Image
                src={
                  network.logo_path !== null
                    ? `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${network.logo_path}`
                    : mediaPlaceHolder
                }
                width={"300"}
                height={"500"}
                className=" rounded-lg h-auto w-auto"
                alt={`Logo of ${network.provider_name} `}
                priority={true}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
```

But this approach is [adviced against](https://kuldipem.medium.com/say-no-to-array-index-as-key-in-react-my-approaches-to-tackle-it-that-you-can-use-51153bfa8901)

Instead, you can contact both the `id` and array index to get a unique key

```
 {data.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.display_priority - b.display_priority;
          })
          .slice(0, 21)
          .map((network, index) => (
            <div key={`${network.id}-${index}`} className="flex justify-center">
              <Image
                src={
                  network.logo_path !== null
                    ? `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${network.logo_path}`
                    : mediaPlaceHolder
                }
                width={"300"}
                height={"500"}
                className=" rounded-lg h-auto w-auto"
                alt={`Logo of ${network.provider_name} `}
                priority={true}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
```

Answer (score -1):

Judging by your code it's hard to determine what's the issue without an example of a single item from the `data`. To me it seems like you're trying to access `.id` incorrectyly - either it doesn't exist, or nested on a different level of the object.

Try passing the a different value as a key instead of `network.id`.
For example you can try:

```
.map((network, index) => ( 
  <div key={index} className="flex justify-center">
    ...
  </div>
));
```

If that helps, try checking where the `.id` value really is in the `data` object or whether it's duplicated.